# Can hotel kick me out into ice storm if I don't have more money?

Tags: legal, hotels, emergencies

I've been staying in a hotel for the past month. I work to pay the bill on a daily basis. We are in an ice storm, there's no work. I can't pay. The officials say stay put, Can they kick me out if I can't pay?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Which country is this a question for?

Comment: When you say 'officials' is this the hotel owners? Or are they government or relief officers who have put you up in the hotel?

Comment: In the US, Hotels are not apartments in most cases, so normal landlord laws do not apply. You really need a lawyer if you want to make a case that they do.

Comment: Highly related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14623/what-happens-if-you-cannot-pay-for-a-hotel?rq=1

Comment: Since the lodging seems to be compensation for your work, labour law could also be relevant.

Comment: This question is fundamentally not answerable without some geographic/jurisdictional data. Without that, it's pure speculation, and this question ought to be closed.

Comment: Quote the law you think gives you a right to not pay for your lodging (and supposedly food) just because the weather turned sour on you.

Answer (score 8):

This is from [a guide](http://www.calodging.com/images/uploads/pdfs/ABCsOfEvictingGuests.pdf) published by the California Hotel & Lodging association:

> The mere fact that an innkeeper has a legal
>   right to evict someone does not give the innkeeper the right to carry out the eviction in a
>   manner that would place the person in a position of harm.

Additionally, according to that guide the eviction of a non-paying guest cannot be done by the hotel owner or their security staff, it has to involve the police (who would then also have the responsibility not to put you into a harmful position).

This is based on California law, so it may not apply in your jurisdiction, but in all likelihood the laws are similar. But note that it only applies in situations where there is immediate danger, i.e. until the storm ends.

If the hotel tries to kick you out, threaten to sue them. That should make them stop and do it by the book.

Comment: Never seen an ice storm in California. :)

Comment: -1, without more data from the asker, this answer is of limited utility.

Comment: Every answer is of limited utility. It's the asker who didn't provide enough info. Michael contributed a very good answer and it may well be of use to people who end up here via some Googling.

Comment: @Karlson My first ever visit to California was in May and we were welcomed by snowfall (in [Mammoth Lakes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammoth_Lakes)).  I'm sure ice storms are frequent in winter in the Sierra Nevada.  Plenty of ski resorts there.

Comment: @gerrit Snow yes.  Not the same as Ice Storm

Comment: @Karlson Wouldn't ice storms be possible in the mountains as well?

Comment: @gerrit Highly unlikely in the mountains.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_storm

Comment: Just because he's kicked out of a cozy hotel room doesn't mean he's in physical harm. There's homeless shelters, salvation army, etc. etc. and many communities set up emergency shelters for those caught out in the open during severe weather events like ice storms.

Comment: @jwenting: Sure, and if one of them is just across the street or the hotel gives her a ride to one, that would probably absolve them of liability.

Comment: Other laws are similar to California?  That's clearly a joke, right?